# Different ways Asterisk (* operator) is used in C

Tags: c, pointers

So I know that the * operator is used for multiplication and as a pointer but sometimes I see the * operator and I am not sure what it means. Have a look at this code which defines a matrix

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

/* The data structure representing a matrix */
typedef struct {
    int rows;       /* number of rows */
    int columns;    /* nuumber of columns */
    int **content;  /* matrix elements in a two dimensional array */
} matrix_t;
```

what does a double asterisk used for here?

I assume ** operator is used for pointers in 2d arrays but I am not sure.

Comment: Each `*` means "pointer" in `int **content;`.  `content` points to a pointer to `int`.

Comment: So it basically means pointer to a pointer?@DrewDormann?

Comment: Yup, it's used for 2d arrays in C.

Comment: `type * name` == pointer.  `*name` == dereference, also known as indirection.

Comment: `int *p` is a pointer to a single `int`, but that single `int` could be the first element of an array of `int`. Likewise, `int **q` is a pointer to a single pointer, but it could also point to the first element of an array of pointers.

Comment: Then there are multi-char tokens, like `*=` and `/*` and `*/`.

Comment: It is not a 2-D array, but for an array of 1-D array pointers, and those 1-D arrays need not be the same size (a jagged array). Yes, it has 2 dimensions, if you like, but is not a 2-D array. A 2-D array has all its elements contiguously in memory, but here they are not (necessarily). Only the 1-D arrays which are pointed to must be contiguous.

Comment: Maybe you already know this, but in such cases, always read from right to left, here: the identifier `content` is a pointer to a pointer to type `int`. `content * * int` vs. `int * * content`.

Comment: To be honest, if you ask this question, then more than one level of indirection is a bit to advanced for you at this time.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't declare types with a _t suffix of your own; it's undefined behavior on POSIX systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple indirection is a thing - you can have pointers to pointers, pointers to pointers to pointers, pointers to arrays of pointers, arrays of pointers to pointers, pointers to arrays of pointers to pointers to arrays of pointers to functions returning pointers, etc.

As used here, the intent is that you allocate an array of pointers:

```
matrix_t mat;
mat.content = calloc( 2, sizeof *mat.content );
```

which gives us

```
             int **     int *
             +---+      +---+
mat.content: |   | ---> |   | mat.content[0]
             +---+      +---+
                        |   | mat.content[1]
                        +---+
```

and then for each of those pointers, you allocate an array of `int`:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
  mat.content[i] = calloc( 2, sizeof *mat.content[i] );
```

giving us

```
             int **     int *                     int
             +---+      +---+                     +---+
mat.content: |   | ---> |   | mat.content[0] ---> |   | mat.content[0][0]
             +---+      +---+                     +---+
                        |   | mat.content[1] -+   |   | mat.content[0][1]
                        +---+                 |   +---+
                                              |       
                                              |   
                                              |   +---+
                                              +-> |   | mat.content[1][0]
                                                  +---+
                                                  |   | mat.content[1][1]
                                                  +---+
```

The *expression* `mat.content` has type `int **`, so the expression `*mat.content` has type `int *`; thus, `sizeof *mat.content == sizeof (int *)`.  Similarly, the expression `mat.content[i]` also has type `int *` (`*p == p[0]`), so `*mat.content[i]` has type `int`, so `sizeof *mat.content[i] == sizeof (int)`.

Because of how array subscripting works, `mat.content[i][j]` works exactly the same way as if you had declared `mat.content` as a regular 2D array of `int`.  It's just instead of all the rows being allocated in a single contiguous chunk, they're allocated piecemeal.

General rules:

```
T *p;        // p is a pointer to T
T *ap[N];    // ap is an array of pointer to T
T (*pa)[N];  // pa is a pointer to an array of T
T *fp();     // fp is a function that returns pointer to T
T (*pf)();   // pf is a pointer to a function that returns T

T **p;       // p is a pointer to a pointer to T
T ***p;      // p is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to T

const T *p;  // p is a pointer to const T - you can write to p, but not *p
T const *p;  // same as above
T * const p; // p is a const pointer to T - you can write to *p, but not to p
```

When used in an *expression*, the `*` "dereferences" the pointer - if you have a declaration like

```
int x;
int *p = &x;
```

the *expression* `*p` acts as kind of an alias for `x`:

```
*p = 10; // does the same thing as x = 10;
```

The object `p` stores the location of `x`, and the type of the expression `p` is `int *` (pointer to int).  The expression `*p` is equivalent to the expression `x` - not only does it yield the value stored in `x`, you can write a new value to `x` *through* `*p` as shown above.

The declarations above give us this relationship:

```
 p == &x // int * == int *
*p ==  x // int   == int
```

The array subscript expression `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)` - given a starting address designated by `a`, offset `i` elements (*not bytes!*) from that address and dereference the result.

```
*p == *(p + 0) == p[0]
```

Arrays are not pointers, nor do they store a pointer to their first element.  Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element.  This is important - if you declare an array

```
int a[10];
```

`a` does not store an address to its first element; instead, any time the compiler sees the *expression* `a` outside of the contexts listed above, it will basically replace it with something equivalent to `&a[0]`.